# display the count of shown divs on selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am displaying 6 div s in a div container.I am using some checkboxes as filters in this,on click of which i am hiding and showing the div s on basis of data attributes given to the div s.

I am able to hide and show the divs as desired.but at the same time i want to show the count of divs which are shown on the screen.For example,we have 4 div s at start,so at start count should be 4,and when we check a checkbox,with that 2 div s are hidden and 2 are shown.

So the count will be 2.

below is my div arrangment

HTML :

```
<div id="prod">
<div class="content" data-name="John" data-location="UK">John</div>
<div class="content" data-name="Peter" data-location="Aus">Peter</div>
<div class="content" data-name="Peter" data-location="UK">Peter</div>
<div class="content" data-name="Peter" data-location="UK">Peter</div>
<div class="content" data-name="John" data-location="Aus">John</div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="name" id="Peter">Peter
<input type="checkbox" class="name" id="John">John
<input type="checkbox" class="location" id="UK">UK
<input type="checkbox" class="location" id="US">US
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a=$("input.name");
var b=$("input.location");
var name=new Array();
var location=new Array();
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")){
   $('.container >div').hide();
   if(this.className == "name"){
       console.debug("name checked");
       name.push($(this).attr('id'));
    }else if(this.className == "location"){
       console.debug("location checked");
       location.push($(this).attr('id'));
    }
     console.log(name+","+location);
     displaydivs(name,location);
}else{
 $('.container >div').show();
 if(this.className == "name"){


     var index = name.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
     if (index > -1) {
        name.splice(index, 1);
     }       
 }else if(this.className == "location"){

 alert("location");
     var index = location.indexOf($(this).attr('id'));
     if (index > -1) {
        location.splice(index, 1);
     } 
 }
 displaydivs(name,location);
}     
});


function displaydivs(name,location)
{
    $(".container >div").hide();
if(name.length > 0 & location.length > 0){ 
    $.each(name, function( index, value ){
        var temp = $(".container >div[data-name="+value+"]")[0];
        var data = $(temp).attr("data-location");
        var idx = location.indexOf(data);
        if(idx > -1){

          $("#prod >div[data-name="+value+"][data-location="+data+"]").show();
        }            
    });  
    $.each(location, function( index, value ){
        var temp = $(".container >div[data-location="+value+"]")[0];
        var data = $(temp).attr("data-name");
        var idx = name.indexOf(data);
        if(idx > -1){

       $("#prod >div[data-name="+data+"][data-location="+value+"]").show();
        }            
    });
}
else if(name.length > 0 & !(location.length > 0)){ 
    $.each( name, function( index, value ){

        $("#prod >div[data-name="+value+"]").show();
    });
}
else if(!(name.length > 0) & location.length > 0){ 
    $.each( location, function( index, value ){

        $("#prod >div[data-location="+value+"]").show();
    });
}else{
    $("#prod >div").show();

}
}
```

i basically want to display the count div s getting viewed in screen.like start it should be 5 and then if some thing is checked,lets say Peter and then count should be 3 as there are 3 div s with data-name as peter and then if both peter and john are checked then count should be 5 as there are 5 div s containing these two names,Next if u select peter and Location as UK then count should be 2, if Peter and location as UK and Aus then count should be 3 as Peter with UK and Aus are in total as 3.

Please help me out in above scenario.how should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
function getCount()
{
    count = 0;
    $('.content').each(function(index, element) {

        var u_id = '#'+$(this).data('name');
        var l_id = '#'+$(this).data('location');
        if($(u_id).is(':checked') || $(l_id).is(':checked'))
        {
            count=count+1;
        }
    });
    return count;
}
```

Comment: where should i insert the above function??